# Splunk Alert - custom trigger condition - trigger alert if percentage failure increase by 1% in last 15 minutes

Tags: monitoring, splunk, splunk-query, alerts

I am trying to send alerts if in last 15 minutes failureThreshold increases by 1%, Following is the Splunk query that returning percentage failureThreshold:

```
index=*apiGateway* Consumer=* ServiceName=creditcard.* host=*gateway* HTTPStatus=* earliest=-15m@s 
| stats count as Total count(eval(HTTPStatus > 499)) as Failure 
| eval failureThreshold=Failure*100/Total 
| table failureThreshold
```

from Alert window - I am running this query after every 5 minutes and choose custom trigger condition, need suggestions how to check condition failureThreshold > 1

[image]

Comment: Hello Sachin
Have you tried `search failureThreshold > 1`  ?

Comment: yes, I tried and the problem is in alert window failureThreshold value is not recognized ( as it need some reference variable to get values of failureThreshold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it easier and more reliable to put the alert threshold in the search and have the alert trigger when the number of results is not zero.

```
index=*apiGateway* Consumer=* ServiceName=creditcard.* host=*gateway* HTTPStatus=* earliest=-15m@s 
| stats count as Total count(eval(HTTPStatus > 499)) as Failure 
| eval failureThreshold=Failure*100/Total 
| where failureThreshold > 1
| table failureThreshold
```